# Multiple selectors using same event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to Jquery so any help on this would be appreciated.

Hope this makes sense:

I have built a site based upon Twitter Bootstrap have multiple collapse divs, each triggered by its own button. These buttons all share the same class.

I'm using the "show" and "hide" events to change the background image css property (from a "+" to indicate expand to a "-" to indicate collapse).

I'm still unsure how to use "this" to target the current element so I can only change the background on the button showing/hiding its div.

```
$('#myDiv').on('show', function () {

    $("a.myBtn").css({
        'background': 'url(/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/bootstrap/img/btn_collapse.png) no-repeat',
        'background-position': 'right 3px'
    });
});

$('#myDiv').on('hide', function () {

    $("a.myBtn").css({
        'background': 'url(/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/bootstrap/img/btn_expand.png) no-repeat',
        'background-position': 'right 3px'
    });

});
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the show/hide events for this – why don’t you use the click events on the buttons themselves?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to simplify this by creating two css classes e.g.

```
.expanded {
  background: ....
}

.collapsed{
  background: ....
}
```

In you jquery you can then just have one handler `$(".myBtn").on ('click') ....`

In your handler you can check using `hasClass ()` to see if which state it is coming from and then use `addClass` and `removeClass` to change the css class

e.g.

```
  if ($(this).hasClass ('expanded') {
     $(this).addClass ('collapsed');
     $(this).removeClass ('expanded');

  }
```

Comment: OK. In this instance I decided to use a bit of "if or else" - seems to work here: `$(".myBtn").on ('click' , function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass ('expanded')) {
     $(this).addClass ('collapsed');
     $(this).removeClass ('expanded');
  }
  else {
     $(this).addClass ('expanded');
     $(this).removeClass ('collapsed');
  }
});`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myDiv').on({
  'show':function() {
        //in the line below, $(this) represents $("#myDiv");
        $(this).doSomething();
        $("a.myBtn").removeClass("expand").addClass("collapse");
   },
   'hide':function(){
        $("a.myBtn").removeClass("collapse").addClass("expand");
   }
});
```

Comment: So are you both saying that even though my button class is a.myBtn, I can add/remove an additional class while maintaining the identifier a.myBtn?

Comment: [I can only speak for my answer.] Yes, you can add or remove one or more classes using addClass/removeClass, and note the chaining syntax I used to call multiple methods on one jQuery selector.

Comment: I'll probably have at least 10 of these divs with corresponding buttons. Do I need to write the above function for each of them, or is there a way to write a similar function that will work for all of them?

Comment: You can easily address all of them by assigning them all a class in common. If you assign all the divs a class called "changeMe", then your jQuery $("div.changeMe") will hit all  of them.